# Change debian kernel had no effect

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I upgraded my virtual machine from Wheezy to Jessie using debian provided help. The last step was to install new kernel do I did.

```
> apt-get install linux-image-amd64
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 [33.8 MB]
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
Setting up linux-image-amd64 (3.16+63) ...
```

I can see that `/vmlinuz` points to `boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64`. I run `reboot` twice but `uname -a` still says Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64, though I cannot find any suck kernel on my disk. I did not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What hypervisor are you running?  Is this VM running on your local machine or in the cloud?

Some hypervisors do not use the kernel within the VM, they use a special version of the Hypervisor's kernel.  In that case you cannot change the kernel, or you have to make a tech support request to the hosting provider.

Comment: Admin wrote me that hypervisor assigned kernel is configured.